# Implementing a loop calculation on pandas rows based on chain

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, chain

I have below block of codes,

```
import pandas as pd
dat = (pd.DataFrame({'xx1' : [3,2,1], 'aa2' : ['qq', 'pp', 'qq'], 'xx3' : [4,5,6]})
        .sort_values(by = 'xx1')
        .reset_index(drop = True))
dat
for i in range(1, dat.shape[0]) :
    if (dat.loc[i, 'aa2'] == 'qq') :
        dat.loc[i, 'xx3'] = dat.loc[i - 1, 'xx3']

dat
```

I am wondering if the second block of codes i.e.

```
for i in range(1, dat.shape[0]) :
    if (dat.loc[i, 'aa2'] == 'qq') :
        dat.loc[i, 'xx3'] = dat.loc[i - 1, 'xx3']
```

can be implemented using `chain` in continuation with the first block. Means, I am hoping to have below sort of things,

```
dat = (pd.DataFrame({'xx1' : [3,2,1], 'aa2' : ['qq', 'pp', 'qq'], 'xx3' : [4,5,6]})
        .sort_values(by = 'xx1')
        .reset_index(drop = True)
        ### implement the for loop here
     )
```

Any pointer will be very helpful

Comment: Can ‘qq’s be consecutive?

Comment: `qq` may not be consecutive

Comment: when you say *may not be consecutive*, do you mean, `qq` is never consecutive? i.e. there's always a `pp` between two `qq`s?

Comment: As I said `qq` may not be consecutive, I meant that 1) there could be consecutive `qq` values and/or 2) there could be one or more `pp` values between two `qq` and/or 3) there could be other value(s) e.g. `xxx` between two `qq` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `assign` `xx3` again by `mask`ing the `qq` values and forward-filling it. Since the loop starts from `index=1`, we start the mask from `index=1`:

```py
dat = (pd.DataFrame({'xx1' : [3,2,1], 'aa2' : ['qq', 'pp', 'qq'], 'xx3' : [4,5,6]})
        .sort_values(by = 'xx1')
        .reset_index(drop = True)
        .assign(xx3 = lambda df: df['xx3'].mask(df['aa2'].eq('qq') & (df.index!=0)).ffill().astype(df['xx3'].dtype))
      )
```

Output:

```py
   xx1 aa2  xx3
0    1  qq    6
1    2  pp    5
2    3  qq    5
```

Comment: This is awesome. Many thanks. One question though. How can this be modified if I have multiple conditions i.e. perform the same is value of `qq` or `isna`?

Comment: @BrianSmith you can add more conditions to the condition inside `mask`.